# SQL string split and value increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

**R/005/2016-17**

This varchar value i have in a table, i need to add 1 to 005.

i need output **R/006/2016-17** for the next entry

How can i split the string and add one.

Comment: What you really need to do is turn this 3 valued column into 3 columns. Storing multiple values in a single column violates 1NF and causes lots of problems. What you are facing here is because of poor table design. If this was three columns this would be simple. As it is defined you will have to split your string, add one to the value in the middle, then turn it back into a string and finally concatenate this back into a single value. UGH!!!

Comment: I Agree with @SeanLange - you can use `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) ` and find Max in column and add 1, but if you have large data - it is not recommended - and storing in three column is better choice.

Answer (score 3):

Your table demonstrates just how bad things can be when you don't properly normalize your data. But you can do this using some string manipulation. I would strongly urge you to split this into the appropriate columns instead of keeping this all crammed together.

This code will produce the desired output based on your sample data.

```
declare @Something varchar(20) = 'R/005/2016-17'

select parsename(replace(@Something, '/', '.'), 3) + '/' + right('000' + convert(varchar(3), convert(int, parsename(replace(@Something, '/', '.'), 2)) + 1), 3) + '/' + parsename(replace(@Something, '/', '.'), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ParseName(), I have a TVF which may help.  If you can't use the UDF, the logic is easily ported into the CROSS APPLY

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,String varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'R/005/2016-17'),
(2,'A/119/2016-18')

Update @YourTable 
   Set String = Pos1+'/'+right('000000'+cast(cast(Pos2 as int)+1 as varchar(25)),len(Pos2))+'/'+Pos3
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row](A.String,'/') B

Select * from @YourTable
```

The Update Table

```
ID  String
1   R/006/2016-17
2   A/120/2016-18
```

The UDF if Needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
          ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
     From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
)
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-Row]('John Cappelletti',' ')
```

Comment: If they can use the xml datatype they have parsename. It is built in to sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange are you sure?  I'm pretty sure XML is in 2008 while ParseName() is 2012+

Comment: PARSENAME came out in 2005. The documentation is not very clear on this. I just double checked on our 2005 instance and it is there. I have been using parsename far longer than 2012. :) And 2005 is also when the xml datatype came to be.

Comment: @SeanLange No kidding!  I feel cheated.  Even MSDN lists older versions as 2012.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange I was a slow adopter for XML.  Wish I paid more attention earlier.  Keep in mind that I'm the guy that when Windows was first released, I asked "Who has to work on more than one program at a time?"

Comment: 640K ought to be enough RAM for anybody. :D

Comment: @SeanLange You have to admit, those early guys were hard-core.  Seriously Lotus 123 on two floppy disks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126358/discussion-between-sean-lange-and-john-cappelletti).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Computed Columns when create table for this type case.

Eg:-

[EmployeeNo]  AS ([PreFix]+ RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)) PERSISTED,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx